# Querying Multiple Entity Groups

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have entities of kind Users. Each user entity belongs to a different
entity group. Is it possible to perform a query by Kind with equality
filters on certain properties e.g date_of _birth and zipCode. The aim
is to get the entities with no intention of modifying them

Comment: Can you post your classes? and if you are using the ndb datasotre...

Comment: Yes. Entity groups only really come into effect for queries when you start using ancestor as a qualifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can add filter to query like this:

```
Query q = new Query(kind);
q.addFilter("zipCode", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "11000");
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
return pq.asIterable();
```